# Cross validation for different data types?

Tags: cross-validation, model-selection

Imagine I have some ground truth represented by vector $\vec{t} = (t_1,...,t_n)$. This ground truth can be measured using a variety of experimental techniques. We can write the data matrix as say $X = (x_{i,j})$ for $1\leq i \leq n$ and $1\leq j\leq m$ for $m$ different experimental techniques. These techniques have potentially different accuracies!

Now, experiments are expensive, so I can only measure $x_{i,j}$ for some $i$ and $j$ - otherwise the value is missing.

Further still, I can develop a model able to take in an incomplete data matrix $X = (x_{i,j})$ and predict the ground truth $\vec{t}$ - even when I do not have any measurements for ground truth entry $i$.

Here's my question :- how can I validate my model?

I had an idea: how about doing some kind of cross validation whereby I create a model using all but 1 experimental measurement type, so using $m-1$ experimental techniques, then try to predict the final experimental $m^{th}$ experimental measurement from this.

If I do this cross validation for all experimental techniques, one would hope to combine these models in some consistent way to create a final model.

Please let me know should one have any suggestions / starting points for literature.

P.S., To complicate the matter, we are not sure if missing values are because because the experiment was not performed, or because it failed to produce a viable measurement. I am primarily thinking of experiments with binary outcomes.

Comment: To clarify, do you have a calibration dataset including both experimental measurements and known ground truth values?

Comment: @user20160 - some experimental methods are better than others, but there is no ground truth, no.

Comment: In that case, how do you propose to relate measurements to ground truth? I see how a model could account for relationships between different measurement techniques. But, it seems like some additional assumptions would be needed to claim that you can predict ground truth.